# Cassandra CQL3 update slow performance on a single wide row

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I am attemping to use the following CQL3 statement to update a column family 50k times:

```
 update column_family
 set    value_1    = ?,   
        value_2    = ?,   
        value_3    = ?,   
        value_4    = ?    
 where  partition_key = ?                
 and    column_key    = ?;
```

The important piece to state here is that the partition_key is the same for all 50k records.

I either send cassandra this query 50k times, or batch up 5000 at a time using BATCH ... APPLY BATCH;  Either way, it takes roughly 10 minutes with no network latency to speak of.  I know that the internal structure is one wide row.  Is this why it is slow?

Also do I have the internal structure correct?  If the CF creation CQL looks like this:

```
create table column_family (
    partition_key varchar,
    column_key uuid,
    value_1 int,
    value_2 timestamp,
    value_3 double,
    value_4 double,
    PRIMARY KEY(partition_key , column_key)               
);
```

Then my internal CF would have partition_key as a partition key, the column keys would be column_key(0)#value_1, column_key(0)#value_2, column_key(0)#value_3, column_key(0)#value_4, coulmn_key(1)#value_1 .......

Comment: Have you rules out it being client bound?  Which client are you using?  Have you tried inserting batches in parallel?

Comment: I have not I guess.  I am using astyanax.  I have not tried parallelizing.  I'll look into #1 and #3, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

50K inserts in 10 minutes is 12ms per insert on average. While that is slow, it's not extremely slow. If you have a slow network, if you do work between requests, and send only one request at a time then I can totally see it being normal. It sounds unlikely that Cassandra is your bottleneck. Try parallelizing your client or try a driver that supports CQL3 pipelining (like the Datastax driver).

Answer (score 1):

To rule out a performance issue on server side, you should check out the write latency..

You can check it using [datastax' ops center](http://www.datastax.com/docs/opscenter/online_help/performance/cluster_metrics). 
If not, try the cli tool that comes with C*.

```
nodetool cfhistograms keyspacename cfname
```